# Shopify - GraphQL - Expected Name Found String

Tags: graphql, shopify

I've just started using Shopify's GraphQL - looks very helpful, I want to gather all users that have purchased a specific variant.

So in Postman, I've got my request, which is getting the orders along with the variant IDs.

However I want to get only orders with specific variant id.

I'm trying this request, but I keep getting `Parse error on \"gid://shopify/ProductVariant/123456\" (STRING) at [9, 21]",`

And then when I try the query on the [explorer on the Shopify page](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/graphql-admin-api/graphiql-explorer), it says `Expected Name Found String`.

Any ideas what the correct should be?:

```
{
  orders(first: 5) {
    edges {
      node {
        lineItems(first: 5) {
          edges {
            node {
              variant {
                id: "gid://shopify/ProductVariant/123456"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Update: I figured how to do it, I needed `orders(query: "lineItems.edges.node.variant.id:123456", first: 10) {`

Comment: However I don't know how to do multiple querys using `AND` or `&&` doesnt seem to work

Comment: Actually the above doesnt entirely work - its not returning precisely `123456`, the results also includes things like `123872`

Answer (score 0):

Try check shopify GrapQl use age documentation. From what I can see from the code posted above maybe the it is requesting for a data type Name and found a data of type String instead. And moreover your arguments should be inside( ) instead of the curly braces{ }.

Something  like this
    Variant(id: "gid://shopify/ProductVariant/123456")
    {
     ...query string
    }